# postgres removes microseconds from now()

Tags: postgresql

My local postgres instance, version 12, removes the microseconds from my timestamp.

The column type is timestamp with out time zone.
My query is `UPDATE trash SET updated_at = now() WHERE id = 164` and when I do `select id, updated_at FROM trash WHERE id = 164` the microseconds are gone.

However, `SELECT now()` returns micrsoseconds.

Is there some configuration or something else that would help me understand why the microseconds aren't persisted?

Comment: Are you  sure that it's removing the microseconds, and that it's not how the field is being displayed? I.e. `SELECT now(), now - updated_at, updated_at FROM trash WHERE id = 164`.

Comment: i guess the field is declared as ```timestamp(0)``` and intended not to save seconds fraction at all

Comment: My column is `timestamp(0)`. What does that mean?

Comment: Amazing enough there is documentation that tells you; [datatype-datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet `updated_at` is of type `timestamp(0)` so that it discards fractional seconds.